# What can I do fix this syntax error that I have in chapter eight of the Rails Tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm going through the Rails Tutorial and am on chapter 8 (where I am working on an authentication system). When I run the test suite that I've prepared so far, I get 8 identical errors with the following information:

```
rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/sessions/new.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected ':'
   ..._buffer.append= ( f.text_field: :email );@output_buffer.safe...
```

My test code and embedded ruby code is in the following gist: https://gist.github.com/2997168.

Line 9 of `new.html.erb` is:

```
<%= f.text_field: :email %>
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For future reference, it's best to include the offending code when possible in your question itself. In this case the file and line is well-known.

Comment: Hi, Dave. Sorry about that! I was having a bit of trouble formatting it. Next time I will be sure to include the code in the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

The error is in your view:

```
<%= f.text_field: :email %>
                ^-here
```

Remove the colon and you should be fine.